# Gutenberg RichText Custom block Attributes. "Array & Children" or "String & HTML"?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm tring to make dynamic custom block using "RichText" and wondering how to set it's attributes.
By checking examples on the internet, some people set its attributes to "Array & Children" but I also found the examples with "HTML & Class Name".

I tried both patterns(Pattern A and B below) but their results on frontend are exactly the same.
I'd like to know the difference between them and which is the better way.

Pattern A

```
attributes: {
    message: {
        type: 'array',
        source: 'children',
        selector: '.message',
    }
},
```

Pattern B

```
attributes: {
    message: {
        type: 'string',
        source: 'html',
        selector: '.message',
    }
},
```

edit & save functions

```
edit: props => {
    const {attributes:{message}, className, setAttributes} = props;
    const onChangeMessage = message => {
        setAttributes({message});
    }
    return(
        <div className={ className }>
            <RichText
                tagName = "div"
                multiline = "p"
                onChange = {onChangeMessage}
                value = {message}
            />
        </div>
    );
},
save: props => {
    const {attributes:{message}} = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="message">
                <RichText.Content
                    value = {message}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );

},
```

Answer (score 3):

Attribute sources are used to define how the block attribute values are extracted from saved post content. They provide a mechanism to map from the saved markup to a JavaScript representation of a block.

Gutenberg uses attributes and attribute sources to parse that HTML out and extract data from it. In order to do this, Gutenberg makes use of the [`hpq library`](https://github.com/aduth/hpq), which is a helper that does exactly this kind of parsing. Each source attribute describes a different function from hpq that’s used to parse an HTML block.

There attributes are passed on to the save and edit functio.

Attributes source depends on your usecase:

**html:** An html source will return you the innerHTML from the markup.

**children:**  Using a children source attribute returns you the DOM nodes as an array of children

> **A children attribute is more flexible to extract complex HTML from your block and edit them and most of the time this what you must be
>   using.**

You can look at the other [`list of attributes provided by RichText here`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-attributes/)  and also refer this really [indepth blog on Attributes](https://reaktivstudios.com/blog/gutenberg-attributes/)

Comment: I still don't understand when to use type array and type string

Comment: with children attributes use type array